# why not selecting multiple rows of same standard_id using SQL query from database?

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin

i have invested much more time in simple query ,i was trying to select different rows of same standard_id and in my database is two such rows which have same standard_id but from them i only getting first row of same standard_id and while second row is missing ,i don't know what's i doing wrong ,
can anyone check please.
your any help would be very helpful.

`my sql query code:`

```
   <?php 
require_once("../header.php");
include_once("adminTitlebar.php");
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    $standard= $_POST['Standard'];
    $student_name= $_POST['student'];
    $sql="SELECT * FROM `student_details` WHERE `st_standard`=2";

    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    print_r($rows);
    die;
    $new_array=array();
    array_push($new_array,$rows);
 }
 else{
    //die("failed to search data due to :".mysqli_error());
}
?>
```

`and stored record of my database is:`

[image]

can only tell me the problems is it in my code or the problems have in database?

Comment: Where is the code that's only getting a single row? And is there a reason you're not using a `$wpdb` query?

Comment: no reason but i am trying to fetch the data by core php

Comment: i am updating the code now please check

Comment: This is core PHP code run against a non-WordPress database table. The WordPress stack is not the right place to be asking this question, It belongs on https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: OK i understand it..whoever i asked to get any help or guide